# Find a substring of 4 consecutive digits and a substring of 3 consecutive digits in a string

Tags: python, string, substring

I have strings of the type:

```
1432_ott_457_blusp
312_fooob_bork_1234
broz_901_6453
kkhas_1781_LET_GROK_234
1781_234_kkhas
```

etc. In other words, each string contains multiple substrings delimited by `_`. The total number of substrings is variable. I look for a substring containing 4 digits, and another one containing 3 digits. As you can see, the two substrings can be located anywhere inside the string. A solution such as

```
import re
three_digits = re.findall('\d{3}')
```

doesn't work, because it will match both the 3 digits substring and the first 3 digits of the 4 digits one. A solution which assumes that both the 3 digits and the 4 digits substring exist is fine, but one that checks this precondition would be even better.

Comment: Might be simpler to split on underscore, then find the parts that are numeric with length 3 or 4.

Comment: Or you could use a regex that looks for a non-digit, then three digits, then another non-digit.  I assume beginning-of-line and end-of-line would count as non-digits, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Something along these lines: https://regex101.com/r/BmgMcT/1

Comment: Use negative lookarounds to match 3 digits not preceded or followed by a digit.

Comment: Matching is greedy, so: `re.findall(r'\d{3,4}', s)`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't get paid more if I use regexes. Feel free to write an answer using splitting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with regular expressions, you're almost there:

```py
import re

input = """1432_ott_457_blusp
312_fooob_bork_1234
broz_901_6453
kkhas_1781_LET_GROK_234
1781_234_kkhas"""

for s in input.splitlines():
    print(re.findall(r'\d{3,4}', s))
```

This doesn't take advantage of the underscore delimiter rule so if you have input like `123abc_000_1111` it will trigger on the `123` as well. If you need to handle such input the regular expression gets a little more complicated:

```py
>>> re.findall(r'(?:_|^)(\d{3,4})(?=_|$)', '999_123abc_abc234_000_1111')
['999', '000', '1111']

# (?:_|^)(\d{3,4})(?=_|$)
# ^^^^^^^---------------- non-capturing group that ensures the
#                         digits start with either '_' or start-of-line
#        ^^^^^^^^^------- capture group for the digits you're looking for
#                 ^^^^^^^ lookahead to ensure the digits end with either
#                         '_' or end-of-line
```

The syntax used above (and much more!) is explained in the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) guide.

Comment: you can add `_` delimiter in the regex to full all conditions

Comment: Woah, amazing! 1) Can you explain what a non-capturing group is? Can you explain why you have  a `(?:` in the first group, but `(?=` in the last? Finally, I think that `_|^` means _match "\_" or beginning of line_ while `_|S` means _match "\_" or end of line_. Correct?

Comment: Added a link to some useful documentation. `|` is logical OR, so you're correct there. `(?:` is use to detect and consume a leading `_` (or beginning-of-line) while `(?=` is used to detect *but not consume* a trailing `_`. If you consumed the trailing `_` then the following digits wouldn't have it to match on and fail early.

Answer (score 1):

I did it seperately for 3consecutive digits and 4 consecutive digits and these can be merged into one

```
def find_substrings(s):
    three_digits = re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)', s)
    four_digits = re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)', s)
    return three_digits, four_digits
```

Output :

```
[('1432_ott_457_blusp', ['457'], ['1432']),
 ('312_fooob_bork_1234', ['312'], ['1234']),
 ('broz_901_6453', ['901'], ['6453']),
 ('kkhas_1781_LET_GROK_234', ['234'], ['1781']),
 ('1781_234_kkhas', ['234'], ['1781'])]
```

In one statement check

```
def find_substrings(s):
    combined = re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(\d{3}|\d{4})(?!\d)', s)
    return combined
```

Just here checking if there are no digits in starting and none at the end. To ensure consistent result.

Comment: Interesting! Can you explain what `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` do?

Comment: checking if their is digits in beginning or following up to it. @DeltaIV

Comment: It will only be trimming when it gets either 4 consecutive digit or 3 consecutive digit and not from others. Like for 5 it won't return you the string.

Comment: Nice! I need to assign the three digit substring to a variable, and the four digits one to another one, as you did in the first piece of code. Do you think it's faster to run 2 regexes and store their results separately, or to run just one (as in your second piece of code) and then run a `if` statement: `if len(combined[0])==3: three_digits. four_digits = combined else: four_digits, three_digits = combined`?

Comment: Like it will interpret 2 times in the upper one but will provide a segregated list of numbers. But in the second one if you are wanting just the list and want to do the operation in one go you can utilize the second one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have strings that have 3 and 4 digits, and there must be 1 occurrence of 3 digits and 1 occurrence of 4 digits, you can split on `_`.

Then filter out the values that have 3 or 4 digits using for example a regex `\A[0-9]{3,4}\Z` and check that the length or the filtered result is 2, and that the length of the results are not the same.

```
import re

strings = [
    "1432_ott_457_blusp",
    "312_fooob_bork_1234",
    "broz_901_6453",
    "kkhas_1781_LET_GROK_234",
    "1781_234_kkhas",
    "1234_1234_kkhas",
    "abc_1234_123_456_test"
]

for s in strings:
    digits = [s for s in s.split('_') if re.match(r"\A[0-9]{3,4}\Z", s)]
    valid = len(digits) == 2 and len(digits[0]) != len(digits[1])

    print(f"{valid} -> {s} -> [{', '.join(digits)}]")
```

Output

```
True -> 1432_ott_457_blusp -> [1432, 457]
True -> 312_fooob_bork_1234 -> [312, 1234]
True -> broz_901_6453 -> [901, 6453]
True -> kkhas_1781_LET_GROK_234 -> [1781, 234]
True -> 1781_234_kkhas -> [1781, 234]
False -> 1234_1234_kkhas -> [1234, 1234]
False -> abc_1234_123_456_test -> [1234, 123, 456]
```